# Different View of ASP.Net Page in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I created an asp.net application and published it sucessfully on a local webserver. 
The problem is, that any page of the application looks different in internet explorer.

I know that the look can be different in different browsers like firefox, ie, chrome...

The funny thing is, that it even looks different in the internet explorer on two different pcs.

When I open it on my laptop, the page looks 'normal' (since i wrote the css on my laptop, so i know how it should normally look), but when i open it on a desktop pc connected to the same lan, it looks very different (some objects are wider or higher). Both IE Versions are the same (9.0.8112.16421).

I really don't know how this is happening.

Begging for some help, please!

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: Provide HTML and CSS markup

Comment: ok, IE is not in compatability mode, checked it, nor is it zoomed.

i'll give you a more specific example.

to add some shadow effect to some elememts i wrote folling into the css file:

 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;  
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;  
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;


On my laptop the shadow shows perfectly up, but not on the desktop PCs.
Same thing with rounded corners.
Since the width and height is all given in percentages, the resolution shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: could it be that the published url is added to trusted site on one PC but not on other? I had this issue where layout was changed when adding to trusted site.

Comment: tried it with trusted sites, nothing happend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.

The Problem was the Quirks-Mode in IE9. I simply added following code inside my head-Element in the SiteMaster:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Because of the Quirks-Mode IE9 pretends to be IE5.5 due to backward compatibility.

This is pretty all you need to do the trick. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities

- IE is in Compatability mode
- IE is zoomed in
- The screen resolutions are different
- The DPI settings are different

Comment: ok, IE is not in compatability mode, checked it, nor is it zoomed. i'll give you a more specific example. to add some shadow effect to some elements i wrote folling into the css file: -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff; -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff; box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff; On my laptop the shadow shows perfectly up, but not on the desktop PCs. Same thing with rounded corners. Since the width and height is all given in percentages, the resolution shouldn't matter, right?